# chapter without number but should be in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have a chapter without a number and would like it included in the table of contents. The tocdepth is set to 0. I use KOMAscript.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% Allow only \chapter in ToC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\addchap{star}

\end{document}
```

[image]

can this be done?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{star}`, just after `\addchap{star}` should do it.

Comment: thank you for the help  - it seems that the simples answer is even simpler: repeat the production of the document step! I forgot that ToC is only correct after repeated processing. Me culpa!  (my real problem was to find `addchap`!)

Comment: `\addchap` includes the chapter in TOC automatically. Maybe you need an additional run.

Comment: exactly! stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The example, as initially posted, works. It needs an additional run.

The important point is to use `addchap` for `scrbook` (not `\chapter*`).